# The directory /home/vsts/work/1/s contains no Terraform configuration files. In Azure Devops trying to create Azure resource

Tags: azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create Azure virtual machine with Terraform and Azure Devops. I'm getting below error.
"The directory /home/vsts/work/1/s contains no Terraform configuration files."
Below is my .yml file.

```
resources:
- repo: self
steps:
- task: TerraformInstaller@0
  inputs:
    terraformVersion: '0.12.3'
- task: TerraformTaskV1@0
  displayName: 'Init terraform'
  inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      backendServiceArm: 'Free Trial'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'terraformtest-rg'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'terraformtestrgdiag'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: 'bootdiagnostics-terraform'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform'
- task: TerraformTaskV1@0
  displayName: 'apply status'
  inputs:
      terraformFile: './terraform/terra/main2.tf'
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'apply'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'Free Trial ()'
```

Comment: I suspect you need to add `terraformFile: './terraform/terra/main2.tf'` to the first tf step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The directory /home/vsts/work/1/s contains no Terraform configuration files. In Azure Devops trying to create Azure resource

According to the error:

```
the directory /home/vsts/work/1/s contains no Terraform configuration files
```

It seems you have run the command in the wrong folder. You have to be in the directory that contains your configuration files before running `init`.

So, you could add the arguments like `workingDirectory` in the first task `TerraformTaskV1`, like:

```
workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\terraform\terra'
```

Hope this helps.